# Android Opensource Project build error `FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja`

Tags: android, build, compiler-errors

I became interested in the Android's source code. I precisely repeated all the steps from the official guide [source.android.com](https://source.android.com) to compile it.

**I tried to compile it and I got:**

```
... error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared
object file: No such file or directory
```

**To fix it:**

Arch: [Enable multilib](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_repositories#multilib),`sudo pacman -S lib32-ncurses`

Ubuntu: `sudo apt install libncurses5:i386`

---

**Then i tried to compile again**

Next time i got no errors messages except exit status 1

```
[100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b 
out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build
-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
21:03:08 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (24:14 (mm:ss)) ####
```

When there are no error messages, I can't guess what's the matter

**But i know, what:**

- This error is independent of linux distribution
- Deleting and downloading all sources again cannot fix this error
- Before I get this error, my computer freezes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that your ninja process is getting killed. That's probably because it tries to use too much RAM: we currently allow ~3.5GB RAM per workspace, so the Linux OOM-killer will kill any process that makes your workspace use more than that.

In order to use less RAM, could you please try building with fewer processes? E.g. with:

> $ make -j2 aapt

Comment: Thakg you a lot! I just switched to tty2, killed the desktop environment and it compiles now! Yay

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but the error log is as below.  

ninja: no work to do.
[100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: external/cpuinfo/Android.bp:42:1: "libcpuinfo" depends on undefined module "libclog"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
20:25:14 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

Comment: Nice!!.....0000

Answer (score 0):

For others who are running into this issue even after reducing the number or processes or physically adding RAM, increase swap space. I followed a "how-to" on DigitalOcean on how to do this without altering partitions:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-debian-11

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build with less RAM(~16GB), you can increase the Swap memory. Make sure that you have a total of RAM + Swap memory of more than 32GB.
Follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-22-04) to increase Swap space after installation.

Also, increase the swappiness to closer to 100, so that the cache will be frequently moved to Swap, freeing RAM for processing. Of course, this will reduce the build speed because of the additional swap process(for frequently moving data between RAM and Swap), but it will keep the build alive.

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80
```

I have a hexa-core Ryzen 5 with 16GB RAM. With an additional swap, I was able to build with six threads(even though the CPU supports up to 12)